# Constructing topology on $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Fix an infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb Z$ whose complement $\mathbb{Z}\setminus A$ is also infinite. Construct a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ in which:

(a) $A$ is open

(b) Singletons are never open (i.e $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\{n\}$ is not open).

(c) For any pair of distinct integers $m$ and $n$, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $m \in U$ and $n \in V$.

My solution: 
I know this is wrong but I don't understand why, so please be as detailed as possible. 
I think the Furstenberg topology satisfies all these conditions. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all arithmetic progressions on $\mathbb Z$, then an open set $U \in  \mathcal{B}$ will be of the form  $Z(m,b) = \{mx + b: x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where $m$ and $b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m\ne 0$.

1. Let $U$ be an open set of $T_{\text furst}$ then $\forall x \in U \ \exists \ Z(m,x) \subseteq U$
2. Every non-empty open set in in $T_{\text furst}$ is infinite.

Then let $A$ be a basic open set of $\mathcal{B}$, then $A$ is infinite and $\mathbb{Z} \setminus A$ is open (can be written as a union of arithmetic progressions) and hence, infinite by (2). Sigletons are not open by (1) and if we describe $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\bigcup_{r=0}^{|m|-1}Z(m,r)$ then it is a union of pairwise disjoint sets which satisfies part c. of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you’re supposed to give a construction that works for *any* infinite $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$ whose complement is also infinite. Your idea works fine if $A$ and $\Bbb Z\setminus A$ happen to be unions of arithmetic progressions, but it doesn’t work if, for instance, $A$ is the set of non-negative integers.

HINT: There is a bijection $h:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q$ such that $h[A]=\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$, and you can use $h$ to define a topology on $\Bbb Z$ that has the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

Note that not all open sets of the Fürstenberg topology are arithmetic progressions (for example, singletons are closed). A subset of $\Bbb Z$ is Fürstenberg-open iff it is the *union* of arithmetic sequences.
But with that correction, your proof can easily be mended, and it can also easily adapted to an *arbitrary* infinite and co-infinite subset $A$: Just pick a bijection of $A$ and $2\Bbb Z$ as well as a bijection of $\Bbb Z\setminus A$ and $2\Bbb Z+1$, for example.

So let us treat the case $A=2\Bbb Z$ and the Fürstenberg topology. Then indeed

- $A$ is open, because $2\Bbb Z$ is an arithmetic progression
- $\{n\}$ is not open, because any non-empty open set contains an rithmetic progression and hence is infinite
- Given distinct $m,n$, we have $m\in  U:=m+2(m-n)\Bbb Z$ and $n\in V:=n+ 2(m-n)\Bbb Z$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

Comment: i don't fully understand why we need a bijection ?

Comment: @jia Via a bijection as described, we can turn a topology that works for the **specific** $A=2\Bbb Z$ into a topology that works for an **arbitrary** given infinite and co-infinite subset $A$.