# Constructing a topology on $\Bbb{Z}$ from a set $A$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I know this question has been asked before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652325/constructing-a-topology-of-bbb-z-whose-complement-is-also-infinite-a-is-op) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794473/constructing-topology-on-bbbz)) still I believe this is not a duplicated question.

I am trying to learn a little bit of topology following [this course](https://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/?resources), and I came across the following problem. Given an infinite subset $A \subset \Bbb{Z}$ with its complement $A^c = \Bbb{Z}/A$ also infinite, construct a topology with the following properties:

- $A$ is open
- Singletons are not open
- For any two elements $n,m\in \Bbb{Z}$, there exists two disjoint open sets $U,V\in \mathcal{T}$ with $n\in U$, $m\in V$.

After a few minutes, I came up with the following construction, but I'm not entirely sure if it is valid, so I appreciate it if anyone can give me some feedback and tell me if it is correct, or where it fails. I know there are probably simpler and more elegant ways to do it, and while you are welcome to share them with me, it's not what I am looking for here. My construction goes as follows:

Let $\mathcal{B}_2 = \{A, A^c\}$. Now, given $\mathcal{B}_n$ let's construct $\mathcal{B}_{n+1}$ as follows:
For each $B\in \mathcal{B}_n$, split it into two infinite complementary subsets, i.e. $B = B_1 \cup B_2$ with $B_1 \cap B_2 = \emptyset$ and both $B_1$ and $B_2$ having infinitely many elements. Furthermore, given any order in $\Bbb{Z}$, let $x,y\in B$ be the first two elements, the splitting must separate them, i.e. $x\in B_1, y\in B_2$.
Then the set $\mathcal{B}_{n+1}$ is defined as the set of all these splittings.

Clearly, $\mathcal{B}_{n+1}$ is a base of $\Bbb{Z}$ since it covers it, and all the elements of $\mathcal{B}_{n+1}$ are disjoint. Furthermore, the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}_{n}$ contains all the previous basis $\mathcal{B}_k$ $k\leq n$

The topology we are looking for is the topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$. $A$ is open because $A\in \mathcal{B}_{2} \subset \mathcal{T}$. Singletons are not open since any element of $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$ has infinitely many elements, and therefore any open set must have infinitely many elements. Finally, given two integers $n,m$ with positions $i_n$ and $i_m$ in whatever order we chose for $\Bbb{Z}$, then property 3 is ensured in the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}_{k}$ as long as $k > \max\{i_n, i_m\}$.

My main concern is about $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$, I'm not really sure if it even makes sense to talk about such a set, and even if it makes sense, I'm not sure if the properties of $\mathcal{B}_n$ are inherited by $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$ (for example, all elements in $\mathcal{B}_n$ are infinite, but I'm not sure this would remain true for $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$)

EDIT: After thinking a little bit more, I thought that maybe it was better to define $\mathcal{B}_{n+1}$ as the set $\mathcal{B}_{n}$ extended with all the splittings. Then I think I can define
$$\mathcal{B}_{\infty} = \bigcup_n \mathcal{B}_{n}$$
is this approach better?

Comment: @BrianMoehring, thank for your comment, is the new approach (defining $\mathcal{B_{n+1}}$ as a superset of $\mathcal{B}_n$) better? Now I can define $\mathcal{B}_\infty$ as an infinite union of the finite basis instead of the limit of those sets, which I think may solve some of the problems with infinity.

Comment: It's better.  Your construction of $\mathcal{B}_{n+1}$ from $\mathcal{B}_n$ is the only part that gives me pause.  We should fix a well-order on $\mathbb{Z}$ before we even start creating $\mathcal{B}_3$ and use it consistently throughout the solution.  Arguably, we should also fix the method by which we're splitting $B$, but I imagine there's some way of choosing a $\mathcal{B}_\infty$ from all possible such bases, so that may be less necessary.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, indeed the order in $\Bbb{Z}$ should be fixed from the begging (and it should be completely irrelevant, so we can assume it is 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...). Regarding the method, I agree that if we want to do it in practice we need some fix criteria that we can extend indefinitely, but as an abstract procedure, as long as both sets are infinite (so that we can repeat this process indefinitely and ensure that we don't end up with singletons) and make sure that we eventually separate any two numbers, is there any other reason why this could fail?

Comment: I think your idea is right. You can make your construction simpler to understand if you replace $\Bbb{Z}$ by $\Bbb{N}$ under the usual ordering and take $A$ to be the set of even numbers (this involves no loss of generality). I think you will then find that your construction gives a homeomorph of the subset of the [Cantor space $2^{\Bbb{N}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space) comprising the sequences with only finitely many $1$s.